# Why does what the updater tell me vary?

Tags: update-manager, settings

I have updates set to run immediately:

[image]

Why do I sometimes see this window, with "Updates are ready to install":

[image]

And sometimes see this, with "X.x MB to download":

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download was triggered by the "security" setting. "when there are security updates" does not mean it downloads just the security updates. It will download all updates (and (I assume) will only install the security related updates).

The image without the download did not have a security update.